# screen auto fit in android

Tags: android, screen

I have written an application for android I want it to work on phones with different screen size. This is my main.xml code :

```
 <?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

 <AbsoluteLayout
 android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1.11"
 android:background="@color/dRed">

<Button
 android:id="@+id/Button02"
android:layout_width="285dp"
android:layout_height="76dp"
android:layout_x="122dp"
android:layout_y="340dp"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:text="Exit"
android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
android:textSize="30dip"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button01"
android:layout_width="285dp"
android:layout_height="76dp"
android:layout_x="122dp"
android:layout_y="250dp"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:text="About!"
android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
 android:textSize="30dip"/>

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="285dp"
 android:layout_height="76dp"
 android:layout_x="122dp"
 android:layout_y="159dp"
 android:background="@drawable/border"
 android:text="Play Game!"
 android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
 android:textSize="30dip"/>

   <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="333dp"
   android:layout_height="93dp"
   android:layout_x="105dp"
   android:layout_y="26dp"
   android:text="Smily XO  !!!"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   android:textColor="@color/orange"
   android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
   android:textSize="60dip"/>

 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_x="291dp"
  android:layout_y="26dp"
  android:src="@drawable/nice"/>

   </AbsoluteLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

It fits well in emulator but, does not fit the screen of phones. Is there any command in android that make it to auto fit on different phones?
in this link 
[Androidmanifest.xml My Android App doesn't really fill the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225467/androidmanifest-xml-my-android-app-doesnt-really-fill-the-screen)
I found that I should add the following code but I am not sure to where exactly write this code

```
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Comment: first top linear layout give fill parent fill parent and wht's requirment of absolutelayout it's deperecated so if you have no problem remove it.

Comment: [Absolutelayout is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and usage is highly discouraged. You should instead use a 
[RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) or another valid layout. Absolute layout does not make provisions for difference screen sizes and densities, and therefor doesn't automatically adjust to different devices very well.

You can also look at layout weights if you wish to have child views of a linear layout take up certain weights or proportions on all screen sizes: [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_weight) and [weightSum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aweightSum)

Comment: Thanks. What about "RelativeLayout"? Does it work if I change the layout to the Relative layout?

Comment: @Elton.fd Relative layout let's everything stay relative to each other, regardless of screen size or density. For exmaple, if TextView A is set to always be to the right of textView B, A it will move to the correct position on all devices if B moves. With absolute layout, the position is always stuck at the exact place you put it, so if A moves, B won't move with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use Absolute Layout as it is deprecated. You can use Linear/Relative layout as per your choice/need. Then for having an even look and feel  for all screen resolution you must have a look at this [support multiple screens for android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.)

You may add different layout folders like **layout-large**, **layout-xlarge** and so on  and put your xml in those folders accordingly. Also the use of wrap-content, match-parent is more preffered than using hard-coded height and width. Otherwise you may have to change the height/width of a particular view for each and every xml files that are located in different 
layout folders.

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest file use the following code above application tag ,

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

then `<AbsoluteLayout/>` is completely deprecated from android API,

use `layout` folder in `resources` for small screens,

create `layout-land` folder for landscape orientation,

In case of Tablets and Large Screens-->Create `layout-large-hdpi` folder in Resources,

copy all your layout.xml files into created folders it will automatically adjust itself,,